# Can I connect any android device with ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I came to know that we can use `adb` commands to detect android devices. But posts I read were specifically for HTC phones. So I want to know that can I connect any of my android device with ubuntu 12.x ?  Or I will need to change some settings of that device? There are some local devices as well as sony xperia, about which I am thinking to buy but I want to make sure that by `adb` commands can I connect and use all devices equally on ubuntu or it varies from device to device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under linux no driver is needed for `adb` connectivity. Although a little setup is required to change the `adb` device file permissions to make it accessible by non-root users. Personally I use this [universal udev rule](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/04/universal-udev-rule-for-all-android.html) which works for all android devices regardless of the manufacturer:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:ff420?:*", MODE="0666"
```

Older `adb` versions used to have a hardcoded *VendorID whitelist*. So owners of devices made by non white-listed vendors were required to add their VendorID to the `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`. But this is no longer required.

Comment: so all what I will need to do will be to place `51-android.rules` file in `/etc/udev/` directory of ubuntu and usb debugging mode enable from phone and then adb will be able to connect device?

Comment: what the second command will do ? Is it optional and I can conitnue with noname ?

Comment: find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices -maxdepth 2 -path "*/modalias" -printf "%h\t" -exec cat {} \; | awk -F: '/icFFisc42ip01/ {print $1}' | xargs -i cat {}/idVendor | awk '{print"\n0x"$1}' >>~/.android/adb_usb.ini
grep ^0x ~/.android/adb_usb.ini | sort -u | sponge ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

Comment: those two lines just collect vendor IDs for all currently connected adb devices and add them to the ini file. or you can do it manually

Comment: ok thanks Alex, it is cool that we can use adb to connect with any android device.

Comment: If the phone is not visible with `lsusb`, would ADB still work?

Comment: if `lsusb` does not list your device - `adb` won't be able to work with it in `usb` mode.